# Spark-Can not access first element in an JavaRDD using first()

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

Using `spark` and its `Java` API. I have loaded data to an `JavaRDD<CustomizedDataStructure>` like this:

```
JavaRDD<CustomizedDataStructure> myRDD;
```

And when I do:

```
myRDD.count();
```

it returns value to me, shows that it do contains data, not a `null` RDD.
But then when running:

```
myRDD.first();
```

It should return me a `<CustomizedDataStructure>`, but it gives such error:

```
14:30:39,782 ERROR [TaskSetManager] Task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) had a not serializable result:
```

Why it is not `serializable` ?

Comment: Well, is CustomizedDataStructure Serializable?

Comment: You should answer this question. Cause that's the case ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `first()`, you cause the first element of the RDD to be copied to the driver process. For that to happen, it has to be serializable, and by default that means implement `java.io.Serializable`. My guess is that this custom class does not.

Comment: That's the issue. Is there a different between `Scala.Serializable` and `java.io.Serializable`?

Comment: You need `java.io.Serializable`. `scala.Serializable` is also fine since it's a subtype.